# Spring Integration 6.x http outbound gateway http uri variable expression not evaluating application properties

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-http

We are using xml based configuration in our spring integration application. Code is being upgraded from Spring Integration v5.x to v6.x. With this we see while using http outbound gateway -> http uri variable is not evaluating application properties via expression that worked earlier. This results in error - URI is not absolute.

Following is example of the application configuration:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="sampleGateway"
    request-channel="jsonInputChannel"
    url="{url}/call-some-api"
    http-method="POST"
    expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
    charset="UTF-8"
    reply-timeout="30000"
    reply-channel="nullChannel">
    <int-http:uri-variable name="url" expression="${sample.api.url}"/>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Here sample.api.url is defined in application.properties for environment specific base url.

${sample.api.url} should resolve from application properties and url="{url}/call-some-api" should construct proper url for the gateway. This worked with v5.x and should work with 6.x too. There is no documentation about this ability being removed.

We used logging adaptor to make sure the expression evaluates the application properties and has appropriate value.

Comment: Can you confirm, please, that you project is based on Spring Boot or you really have a `<context:property-placeholder/>` definition? Otherwise that `${sample.api.url}` is not going to be resolved. There was no any change in the framework on the matter. And that indeed supposed to work. It might be also great if you can share some simple project where we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Yes it is a spring boot app. I am able to access the property in other adaptors e.g Logging Adaptor.

Sample source is pushed to https://bitbucket.org/techsera/uri_attributes/src/master/ for your reference.
PS: POM has commented versions for our old version where existing code works. If you run the app just by changing the java and spring boot version in POM, you should see it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the sample project.

After debugging I see that property placeholder is resolved correctly.
But then when come to the `RestTemplate.execute()`, there is this logic:

```
URI url = getUriTemplateHandler().expand(uriTemplate, uriVariables);
```

And the result is like this:

```
https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Fsearch/call-some-api
```

So, all those non-standard symbols (`:` and `/`) are encoded.

You can add `encoding-mode="NONE"` to that `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` or consider to use `url-expression` instead of `url`.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/http/namespace.html#http-uri-encoding

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan for the solution. It works. Looks like encoding on earlier version of code is null and hence URL was returned unencoded. With the upgrade we see it is defaulted to UTF-8. After setting encoding-mode="NONE", URIComponent is returning unencoded url string. We did explore option of using url-expression and that worked for us. Just resulted in lot of changes hence wanted to know why url didn't work with our upgrade. Thanks again!!!